# is specifying a cell's color (in an excel spreadsheet) by its very textual content possible?

Tags: excel, knime

you can fill a cell with '=cos(0)' and you get displayed its value '1'.

is there some similar function(ality) to choose the font-color?

something like '=COLOR(the text to display, #FF0000)'.

if not, how could you achieve something like that?

here is where I come from: I write data to an excel-file (using KNIME btw) and I want to choose the font-color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this question was raised in the [Knime forums](http://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-general/exporting-coloured-or-colored-cells) a couple of months ago, it didn't elicit much response, so I suspect the answer is simply "No". There were plans back in 2007 for Knime to start using Apache POI to write Excel files, which should have allowed formatting, but I don't know if this ever happened... if it didn't, then Knime is probably still just writing a CSV file for Excel, which doesn't support any formatting.

Comment: so there is no inbuilt functionality. i am still wondering if there is a function of the kind I suggested in the OP. apart from that, there must be some kind of a workaround.

Comment: There is nothing of that kind built into Excel itself. Excel provides all manner of options for setting the styles on a worksheet, once it's been loaded into Excel; but if the Knime output is simply a CSV file (as I believe) then there's nothing that can be set in the CSV itself, which can only contain data without any formatting

Comment: What you might be able to do is to create an emty template worksheet with conditional formatting, and then import the file generated by Knime into that template. The conditional formatting will then be applied to the imported data

Comment: i guess, sometimes the answer is, there is no answer. :-/

Comment: Sadly, that is sometimes the case... I don't know if importing to a pre-formatted template might be a viable workround.